# Where should i put my images in my iPhone project?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios4

I'm new to iPhone dev.

Now i have a project and its directory structure looks like this :

```
Tutorial
       \__Tutorial\
                 \__1.png
                 \__TutorialViewController.h
                 \__TutorialViewController.m
                 \__TutorialViewController.xib
                 \__Supporting Files\
       \__Frameworks\
       \__Products\
```

I tried to use [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"] to render an image to the view:

```
 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];
 imageView.image = image;
 [image release];
```

But the image doesn't shows up.

So i wonder where should i place the images ?

And additionally, if i got lots of images (like 1000 number), what should do ?

---

Here's my code :

```
#import "TutorialViewController.h"

@implementation TutorialViewController
@synthesize labelText;
@synthesize imageView;

-(void) click:(id)sender {
    NSString *titleOfButton = [sender titleForState:UIControlStateNormal];
    NSString *newText = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",titleOfButton];
    // Change Image When Clicking Color Button
    if([titleOfButton isEqualToString:@"Blue"]){
        NSLog(@"Blue");
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"a.png"];
    }else{
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];;
        NSLog(@"Else");
    }
    labelText.text = newText;
    [newText release];
}
```

Comment: try adding it in supporting files folder

Comment: you can't release the image if you don't alloc it before. how you manage imageView? by code or xib?

Comment: doesn't [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"] alloc memory itself ? my imageView is defined as an IBOutlet and connect to FileOwner from xib.

Comment: @SimonePistecchia i don't alloc it but it doesn't throws exception.....

Comment: `imageNamed` returns an autoreleased object, so you don't have to release it. Take a deep look at [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html).

Comment: Sorry the right link is [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html)

Comment: xcode do not alloc UIImage itself, but is not necessary to alloc the uiimage. Is strange, is not important the directory. Do you can add the 1.png directly from xib file? it's a test

Comment: then delete file and drag the file again to your project

Comment: But i can see them in Targets-Bundle Resources, i think the xcode have found them already...

Comment: If you have set an object with property, call it with self.imageView.image and is better call the object with a different name like self.myImageView.image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a folder named Resources and add images there.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_0270.PNG"];
imgView_.image = image;
```

I had used the above code and it works fine on my system. May be you haven't connected the outlet for imgView in the interface builder.

EDIT:

The problem I found is you are not adding it as a subview. You should change your code like this :

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"]];

NSString *titleOfButton = [sender titleForState:UIControlStateNormal];
NSString *newText = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", titleOfButton];

// Change Image When Clicking Color Button
if([titleOfButton isEqualToString:@"Blue"]) {
    NSLog(@"Blue");
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_0270.png"];
} else {
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
    NSLog(@"Else");
}

[imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 230, 123)];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];

// labelText.text = newText;
[newText release];
```

Comment: @Neptune I can't find a way to create folder in my xcode 4.1 .

Comment: @Neptune Again, you're calling `release` on an autoreleased object, you can't, you're not the owner of that object. Now it works fine but in the future could crash your application.

Comment: @MrROY Right click on the project name in xCode and select New Group

Comment: @Mat Ok. I had removed the release statement

Comment: @Neptune I create the Resources and it doesn't work... Does it the same as Supporting Files ?

Comment: @MrROY Usually we are putting images in Resources folder. I think both are same. Also make sure you have connected the outlet of imageview.

Comment: @Neptune thanks any way , i have update the code in the topic, is there any stupid problem ?

Answer (score 0):

there is no prbm with ur code. but Some time image become corrupt , due to this reason it not show, try some other images , and if image is not added at bundle path add at

> project target > build phase > copy bundle Resources

. might be it will help.

Answer (score 0):

You have problem at this statement

```
[image release];
```

The easiest way to remember when to use release is `NARC` keyword :)

Always remember to make release call in 4 cases.

> N New
>
> A Alloc
>
> R Retain
>
> C Copy

Comment: NARC, use release only when there No ARC :D

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the first line of your method, if you've connected the `UIImageView` in the xib you don't need to re-alloc it. Moreover call `self.imageView.image` instead just `imageView.image`.