# i am using [UIImage imageNamed:@"a_image.png"]; What path in the project image should be placed

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview

Hello totally new iPhone development 
I opened an empty project 
I'm trying to add a picture to viewcontroler 
Using this code,

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 50)];
imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"a_image.png"];
imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter
```

What path in the project a_image.png should be placed

I tried to put the image in the project
But the code does not know to take the image from there
What else should I do for my picture displayed

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where should i put my images in my iPhone project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10912827/where-should-i-put-my-images-in-my-iphone-project)

Comment: Have you tried using the *Search* on StackOverflow..?

Comment: It doesn't matter where it is on your hard disc as long as you have a reference to it in your bundle.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can put a .png image in resource folder or any folder inside the project like as Supporting file and also you can also make a unique folder for images

check below in the image you can you different .png files are in the supporting file

[image]

Comment: I tried to put the image in the project
But the code does not know to take the picture from there
What else should I do for my picture displayed

Comment: did you add imageview intto view 
Using this  [self.view addSubView:imageview];

Comment: yes Yes I forgot to add the image
[self.view addSubView:imageview]; 
I'm just so new to apple development